# How to calculated a table partition key from alphanumeric string?

Tags: java, oracle12c, database-partitioning

#### Goal:

Create  300 partition table that evenly distributes records on a table.
The primary key is an email address plus the partition key [1-300].
We are not permitted to use a hash partitioned table due to performance issues.

Doing this for number heavy values is easy:
SQL: `MOD(NVL(REGEXP_REPLACE(field_name,'[^0-9]',''),0),300)+1;`
Java: `(int)(Long.valueOf(defaultString(str.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", ""), "0")) % 300) + 1;`

However, doing this for character heavy strings is more difficult to find a good high performance calculation for a similar partition key.

#### Using:

Oracle 12c & Java 1.8

#### Table:

The Table will contain around 200,000,000 records.

#### Non-Desired:

Using DECODE to manually specify a numeric value for each letter.
Complex calculations requiring looping though each character manually.

Comment: How long is a character heavy string? If its 1000s of letters, then you can do a hash to shorten it and use your method. That should still work for 16 characters or so. You can use the same hashing algorithm in Java to get same results.

Comment: 3-200 characters.

Comment: Most hash standards I can think of return an alphanumeric string, did you have a hash method in mind? The following all result in an alpha-numeric string: SHA1, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, MD5

Comment: Was just playing around in sqlfiddle and this seems to work. Lemme now your thoughts: `MOD(rawtohex(SUBSTR(NVL(message,' '), 0, 5)),300) + 1`. Seems simple enough to be quick. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77dbad/11

Comment: Doesn't work with non-numeric strings: ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Seems to work in sqlfiddle. Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a6965/1. I have most scenarios I can think of. Null values, character only strings, number only.

Comment: Try: INSERT INTO log_table (message) VALUES ('some.one@someplace.here')//

Comment: only works for a subset of characters j and above won't work.

Comment: Yea. Trying to fix that.

Comment: Rawtohex returns a character string, but you can use to_number() on the hex string with a format mask containing one x for every hex digit in your string convert the hex value to a number.  A nice thing about hashing functions is they usually return a hex string, so you can use one of the above hash functions and use to_number on a substring.  Doing the same to raw text however is not likely to result in an even distribution.

Comment: Try this: `MOD(to_number(rawtohex(SUBSTR(NVL(message,' '), 0, 6)), 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'),300) + 1` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fd105/45. Substring to shorten string to 6 letters, convert to hex and then to decimal and get mod.

Comment: To Sentinel's point converting to a hex string will not provide even distribution. Also, what is the substring for?

Comment: Also, it still fails if you have a J in the first 6 digits.

Comment: Does using a hash function to calculate a partition key fail to meet your performance related criteria? Pseudo code: `MOD( TO_NUMBER( SUBSTR( RAWTOHEX( HASH( Message ) ), 1, 3 ), 'XXX' ), 300 )`

Comment: Need to be able to calculate it in Java too. Also, RAWTOHEX is not necessary if you use ORA_HASH (hash() isn't a valid function name), however I can't calculate that in java without knowing the hash algorithm.